# Retrieving all number row from JSON response

Tags: php, json, laravel, guzzle

Using Guzzle I am hooking into an API. The API will provide me with a valid JSON object that contains values I require. I have tried several methods to retrieve an array of values located within the response but at this point can only get one per request via the number of the row:

Here is my current code:

```
public function index () {
    //$value = "07332927917462,07332927917455";
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->get('https://example.com/xxx', 
                             [ 'query' => [
                             'secret' => '2acbefghijklmnop',
                             'created' => '2016-01-01']]);

    $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    $array = $data->products;
    $collect = collect($array);
    $unique = $collect->unique('ean');
    $unique->values()->all();


    return dd($unique[0]->ean);
  }
```

In my `return dd($unique[0]->ean);` I am receiving only one EAN value (via the number), so it will look like this;

```
"012345678910"
```

When I try to call it using `return dd($unique->ean);` I receive an error:

[Laravel response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzPRs.png)

Bascially, what I need to do is get all the rows, not just one. so the request would be something like (for example purposes) `return dd($unique[all]->ean);` but I am not sure how to approach this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my response using just `dd($unique);`:

[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu91W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What result do you exactly wanna get?

You could use "reduce" to get a single value from your collection.

Or, if you just want to get a list of "ean"'s, use "map" and return only the ean for every row:

```
$eans = $unique->map(function($item){
    return $item->ean;
})
```

There doesn't seem to be an "extract" method, but this should also work:

```
$eans = $unique->keyBy('ean')->keys();
```

For reference, here are all the collection methods:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-keyby